# SpEL cannot handle 'é'?

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm a french so I put some **é è ê ô û** in my code. (and I don't speek english very well).

I've a method like that in a class `Formulaires`:

```
  public static Formulaire exposé()
```

And in a config spring xml file, I try :

```
<entry 
key="intro" 
value="#{T(com.myproject.Formulaires).exposé()}"/>
```

But Spring says :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (233) 'é'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.Tokenizer.process(Tokenizer.java:193)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.Tokenizer.<init>(Tokenizer.java:47)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:110)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:56)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:1)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpressions(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:128)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseTemplate(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:74)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:119)
    ... 47 more
```

If I put e and not é all is good.

Is there some SpEL limit about accents ?

I use spring 3.0.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accented characters do not exist in a basic UTF-8 character encoding and the Spring XML files probably use that. As the error says, the parser can't handle accented characters.

There's nothing that you can do to easily solve this problem. Accented characters will give problems in other areas of programming too. I think it would be best to prevent using them.

Comment: Fortunatly, there is no problem in other areas of programmming for me with accents, except spring spel. Anyway, I'm going to remove this one. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, assuming you've tried all areas of programming, I'd still suggest to stop using accented characters. It will bite you in some way or the other.

Comment: I'm french too, and this is the first time in my life I've ever seen a method name containing an accent. BRAVO !!! Why not rewriting java so that it accepts "public statique Formulaires exposé" by the way ;-)

Comment: Did you try "#{T(com.myproject.Formulaires).expos&eacute;()}"

Answer (score 0):

Here's more to it . The code below in Tokenizer decides if it's an alphabetic character

```
private boolean isAlphabetic(char ch) {
    if (ch>255) {
        return false;
    }
    return (flags[ch] & IS_ALPHA)!=0;
}
```

Your character é is <=255 but the flags[ch] is initialized by the static block below

```
static {
    for (int ch='0';ch<='9';ch++) {
        flags[ch]|=IS_DIGIT | IS_HEXDIGIT;
    }
    for (int ch='A';ch<='F';ch++) {
        flags[ch]|= IS_HEXDIGIT;
    }
    for (int ch='a';ch<='f';ch++) {
        flags[ch]|= IS_HEXDIGIT;
    }
    for (int ch='A';ch<='Z';ch++) {
        flags[ch]|= IS_ALPHA;
    }
    for (int ch='a';ch<='z';ch++) {
        flags[ch]|= IS_ALPHA;
    }
```

Hence only a-z or A-Z can be considered ..