# Spring @Value with SpEL split : Cannot handle (233) 'é'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

I have error when I trying to split a string that contain french characters (like é,è,à) with @value:

```
@Value("#{'${param.role_list}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> roles;
```

This is the contain of **param.role_list** :

```
Président,Gérant,Directeur général,Associé-gérant,Co-gérant,Directeur Général Délégué
```

I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (233) 'é'
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1481) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1191) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
```

I want to use SpEL language instead of making a split programmatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571992/spel-cannot-handle-%C3%A9/8572009

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not using french characters in code. I am trying to inject a properties in attribute. It is not the same demand

Comment: It doesn't matter, as, in the linked question, the exception was thrown right after using the accented character `é` in the SpEL.

Comment: I get a different result; `[Prï¿½sident, Gï¿½rant, Directeur gï¿½nï¿½ral, Associï¿½-gï¿½rant, Co-gï¿½rant, Directeur Gï¿½nï¿½ral Dï¿½lï¿½guï¿½]
` (on a mac - US - with standard file encoding) and  `[Pr�sident, G�rant, Directeur g�n�ral, Associ�-g�rant, Co-g�rant, Directeur G�n�ral D�l�gu�]` with `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1`. Since it's within a literal, you shouldn't get a parse error. Show the full stack trace and what version of `spring-expression` you are using.